# C++ Garbage Collector - Simple Automatic Memory Management

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, pointers

I made a general smart pointer which fixes the problems of loops between `std::shared_ptr`'s. While use is simple, I feel that my code is inefficient and clumsy. Here it is:

```
/*
 * gc.hpp
 *
 *  Created on: Nov 10, 2021
 *      Author: lambcoder
 */
#ifndef GC_HPP_
#define GC_HPP_
#include <any>

namespace lambcoder{

template<typename T>
class gcpointer;

class garbage_collector final{
    template<typename T>
    friend class gcpointer;

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    friend gcpointer<T> gcnew(Ts&&...);

    static garbage_collector global_gc;
    garbage_collector() {}

    struct Node{
        Node() = default;
        template<typename T, typename... Ts>
        Node(std::in_place_type_t<T>, Node* prev, Node* next, Ts&&... ts):
            prev{prev}, next{next}, obj{std::in_place_type<T>, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...}{}

        Node* prev = nullptr, *next = nullptr;
        std::any obj{};
        std::uint16_t ref_count = 1;

        template<typename T, typename... Ts>
        friend gcpointer<T> gcnew(Ts&&...);
    };
    Node* head{nullptr};
    static enum class State : std::uint8_t {weak, strong} weak_state;
public:
    ~garbage_collector(){
        weak_state = State::weak;
        Node* tmp = nullptr;
        while(head){
            tmp = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = tmp;
        }
    }
};

garbage_collector::State garbage_collector::weak_state = garbage_collector::State::strong;

garbage_collector garbage_collector::global_gc = {};

template<typename T>
class gcpointer{    
    using node_ptr = garbage_collector::Node*;
    node_ptr ptr = nullptr;
    gcpointer(node_ptr ptr) noexcept: ptr{ptr}{}
public:
    constexpr T& operator*(){
        return std::any_cast<T&>(ptr->obj);
    }
    constexpr T* operator->(){
        return ptr ? &this->operator*() : nullptr;
    }
    constexpr operator T*(){
        return this->operator->();
    }

    constexpr gcpointer() noexcept = default;
    constexpr gcpointer(std::nullptr_t) noexcept {};
    constexpr gcpointer(const gcpointer<T>& other) noexcept: ptr{other.ptr} {
        if(other.ptr != nullptr)
            ++ptr->ref_count;
    }
    gcpointer(gcpointer<T>&& other) noexcept: ptr{std::exchange(other.ptr, nullptr)} {}

    gcpointer<T>& operator=(const gcpointer<T>& other) noexcept{
        if(other.ptr == this->ptr) return *this;
        if(ptr != nullptr && --ptr->ref_count == 0){
            if(ptr == garbage_collector::global_gc.head) garbage_collector::global_gc.head = garbage_collector::global_gc.head->next;
            else if(ptr->prev) ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;
            if(ptr->next) ptr->next->prev = ptr->prev;
            delete ptr;
        }

        ptr = other.ptr;
        if(ptr != nullptr) ++ptr->ref_count;

        return *this;
    }
    gcpointer<T>& operator=(gcpointer<T>&& other) noexcept{
        if(other.ptr == this->ptr) return *this;
        if(ptr != nullptr && --ptr->ref_count == 0){
            if(ptr == garbage_collector::global_gc.head) garbage_collector::global_gc.head = garbage_collector::global_gc.head->next;
            else if(ptr->prev) ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;
            if(ptr->next) ptr->next->prev = ptr->prev;
            delete ptr;
        }

        ptr = std::exchange(other.ptr, nullptr);

        return *this;
    }

    gcpointer<T> release() noexcept{
        node_ptr tmp = ptr;
        ptr = nullptr;
        return gcpointer<T>(tmp);
    }

    ~gcpointer(){
        if(garbage_collector::weak_state == garbage_collector::State::strong){
            if(ptr != nullptr && --ptr->ref_count == 0){
                if(ptr == garbage_collector::global_gc.head) garbage_collector::global_gc.head = garbage_collector::global_gc.head->next;
                else if(ptr->prev) ptr->prev->next = ptr->next;
                if(ptr->next) ptr->next->prev = ptr->prev;
                delete ptr;
            }
        }
    }
    template<typename U, typename... Ts>
    friend gcpointer<U> gcnew(Ts&&...);
};

template<typename U, typename... Ts>
gcpointer<U> gcnew(Ts&&... ts){
    if(!garbage_collector::global_gc.head)
        return gcpointer<U>(
                garbage_collector::global_gc.head =
                new garbage_collector::Node(std::in_place_type<U>, nullptr, nullptr, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
        );
    else{
        return gcpointer<U>(
                garbage_collector::global_gc.head =
                garbage_collector::global_gc.head->prev =
                new garbage_collector::Node(std::in_place_type<U>, nullptr, garbage_collector::global_gc.head, std::forward<Ts>(ts)...)
        );
    }
}

}
```

Use and test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gc.hpp"

struct cat{
    cat(){ std::cout << "cat default ctor" << std::endl; }
    cat(const cat&){ std::cout << "cat copy ctor" << std::endl; }
    cat(cat&&){ std::cout << "cat move ctor" << std::endl; }

    cat& operator=(const cat&){ std::cout << "cat copy operator=" << std::endl; return *this;}
    cat& operator=(cat&&){ std::cout << "cat move operator=" << std::endl; return *this;}

    ~cat(){ std::cout << "cat dtor" << std::endl; }
};

struct B;
struct A{
    A(){ std::cout << "A default ctor" << std::endl; }
    A(const A&){ std::cout << "A copy ctor" << std::endl; }
    A(A&&){ std::cout << "A move ctor" << std::endl; }

    A& operator=(const A&){ std::cout << "A copy operator=" << std::endl; return *this;}
    A& operator=(A&&){ std::cout << "A move operator=" << std::endl; return *this;}

    ~A(){ std::cout << "A dtor" << std::endl; }
    lambcoder::gcpointer<B> ptr;
};
struct B{
    B(){ std::cout << "B default ctor" << std::endl; }
    B(const B&){ std::cout << "B copy ctor" << std::endl; }
    B(B&&){ std::cout << "B move ctor" << std::endl; }

    B& operator=(const B&){ std::cout << "B copy operator=" << std::endl; return *this;}
    B& operator=(B&&){ std::cout << "B move operator=" << std::endl; return *this;}

    ~B(){ std::cout << "B dtor" << std::endl; }
    lambcoder::gcpointer<A> ptr;
};

int main(){
    auto gcp = lambcoder::gcnew<int>(2);
    auto gcpcat1 = lambcoder::gcnew<cat>(), gcpcat2 = lambcoder::gcnew<cat>(*gcpcat1);
    std::cout << *gcp << std::endl;

    auto gcb = lambcoder::gcnew<B>();
    auto gca = lambcoder::gcnew<A>();
    gcb->ptr = gca;
    gca->ptr = gcb;
    std::cout << "Done!\n";
}
```

Output:

```
cat default ctor
cat copy ctor
2
B default ctor
A default ctor
Done!
cat dtor
cat dtor
A dtor
B dtor
```

As can be seen from the output, no memory leaks occurred.

**Pros:**

- Easy to use.

**Cons:**

- Involves double allocation per element.
- Doesn't reuse memory space.
- High overhead (up to 26 bytes per element: three pointers and 2 bytes worth of reference count).
- Isn't much better (or better at all) than `std::shared_ptr`
- When in a scenario with two objects (like `B` and `A`) that reference each other, deletion of objects is delayed until the end of execution.
- Finally, custom allocators can't be used.

**Questions:**

- Is this use for this implementation of garbage collection? Does it have ANY advantage over `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`?
- The garbage collector deallocates `Node`'s once their object is deallocated. Should the garbage collector instead reuse the `Node`?
- At the current moment, custom allocators are not allowed because the garbage collector might have to manually deallocate memory, and `Node`'s are untyped and don't store an allocator. Should the design change so that garbage collectors for certain types (passed a certain allocator type in the template arguments) must be declared and `gcpointer`'s created from them? With this approach, one allocation could be eliminated (since `Node`'s would be typed) Usage of this approach would look something like this:

  ```
   lambcoder::garbage_collector<std::allocator<int>> gcint;
   auto gcpi = gcint.gcnew(2);
   lambcoder::garbage_collector<std::allocator<cat>> gccat;
   auto gcpcat1 = gccat.gcnew(), gcpcat2 = gccat.gcnew(*gcpcat1);
  ```
- Should I keep my current design, but add the aforementioned?
- Is there any way to allocate the object *with* its `Node`? Should I?
- Are there any other design changes that are recommended?

Comment: What happens if a loop is unreachable? Because whichever you destroy first, the rest may stumble over.

Comment: @Deduplicator I am not sure what you mean. Have you looked at my code? In the destructor for garbage_collector, I set a flag which basically causes the destructor of the gcpointers to not touch the memory that they point to. Please take a look.

Comment: I wouldn't add garbage collection to C++. Because you take away one of its main strengths : explicit life time managment and predictability. If you need garbage collection there are other more suited languages

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer, I don't think C++ will ever force you to use a garbage collector, but I suppose it could be useful in some instances. Not that I can really think of any =)

Comment: Could you show a practical use case of these ownership loops? I don’t understand why A needs to own B and B needs to own A. I think any program like this can be rewritten in a more logical and simple way where one of the two doesn’t own the other. In modern C++ we have 3 “types of pointer”: unique, shared, naked. The first two imply ownership, the latter implies non ownership. People are afraid of naked pointers, but I think they should be used when referring to something we don’t own.

Comment: @upkajdt I made this just for the fun and experience.

Comment: @CrisLunengo  the point is to get rid of the need for differentiating between shared and weak. Like said, I made this for the fun.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment seemed concending, it was not the intention. We all learn with experimenting, have fun!

Comment: @upkajdt No, you are correct! Sorry that it seemed that I was misinterpreting your comment. I was simply noting that, while C++ doesn't have much use for my class gcpointer, I made this not for any specific use, but just for a personal challenge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, we need to fix the errors.

- The most obvious one is that the `#ifndef GC_HPP_` has no matching `#endif`.
- We're missing an include of `<cstdint>` for the fixed-width integer types.
- We're missing `<utility>` for `std::exchange`, `std::forward` and `std::in_place_type`.

With those addressed, we can inspect the code.

It's not clear why we need exact-sized types, rather than (e.g. `std::uint_fast16_t`).  Is it important that the ref-count overflows once there's 65536 pointers to an object?  I would expect a `std::size_t` to be a safer choice.

`Node` should have deleted copy constructor and assignment operator, to prevent unintended double ownership of the raw pointers `next` and `prev`.

`garbage_collector` itself should also be made non-copyable.

It's better to explicitly default the constructor, rather than provide one with an empty body:

```
garbage_collector() = default;
```

I don't see why `weak_state` is shared across *all* the garbage collector instances.  Shouldn't it be local to each one?

No need for `this->` in the operator definitions:

```
constexpr T* operator->(){
    return ptr ? &operator*() : nullptr;
}
constexpr operator T*(){
    return operator->();
}
```

The common code to decrement reference count and possibly free a node is written out three times.  This should be refactored into a private function.

Overall, I'd say the biggest design flaw is the assumption of a singleton.  Not only does it make it hard to properly unit-test the collector, but it defeats an obvious use case, where a data structure wants to clean up its own members (but only its own) when it is destructed.  That's easily fixed, of course, at the expense of having a reference member in each `Node`.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Toby's answer:

## Remove `operator T*()`

This is quite dangerous: it allows implicit casts from a garbage collected pointer to a raw pointer to the object. Note that [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) doesn't have such a cast operator.

## Consider making `garbage_collector` templated as well

Instead of having one garbage collector for all objects, it is possible to create individual garbage collectors for each type `T`, by making `garbage_collector` a `template<typename T>` as well. This reduces the size of the global linked lists, which might be handy if you do implement some form of intermediate garbage collection.

## Cycles are only cleaned up on program exit

If you want to be better than `std::shared_ptr`, you want to be able to detect and clean up cycles while a program is still running. At the moment, cycles are not cleaned up until the global `garbage_collector` object(s) are destroyed. However, a program might want to ensure at some point that all objects are cleaned up. Consider adding a function to force all objects maintained by a `garbage_collector` to be destroyed.

Of course, it would be better to avoid writing a program where such cycles can occur, but then you probably also wouldn't need a garbage collector anymore.

Comment: Just to add to the last section: there have been some interesting research papers out of IBM about how the information that a reference counting garbage collector maintains can be used to speed up tracing collection of cycles. They built a GC based on that, cleverly named the *Recycler*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Indeed, they wrote several papers about it, like [this one](https://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-bacon/Bacon01Concurrent.pdf).